# Finding the number of digits in repunit

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, repunit-numbers

Find the number of digits in the smallest repunit divisible by $19$.

I believe a repunit number, with $N$ digits, is of the form $ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} 10^k = \frac{10^N -1}{10-1} = \frac{10^N - 1}{9}, $ and is divisible by $n$ if $10^N - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{9n}.$ The solution should be the smallest number N that satisfies $10^N -1 \equiv 0 \pmod{9 \cdot 19}.$ Can somebody finish this off?

Comment: The answer is equal to the period of $\dfrac1 {19}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$10\equiv1\pmod9$, so $10^N\equiv 1 \pmod9$ for all $N\in\mathbb N$,

so your question becomes what is the smallest number $N$ satisfying $10^N\equiv1\pmod{19}$.

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), we know $10^{18}\equiv1\pmod{19}$;

we just have to show that $10^6\not\equiv1\pmod{19}$ and $10^{9}\not\equiv1\pmod{19}$.

**Method 1**

$10^2\equiv5\bmod19$, so $10^3\equiv50\equiv12\bmod19$, so $10^6\equiv144\equiv11$, and $10^9\equiv132\equiv18\bmod19$.

**Method 2**

$10^6-1=(10^3+1)(10^3-1)=(7\times11\times13)(27\times37)$ is not divisible by $19$.

By [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion),  $10^9-1\equiv\left(\dfrac{10}{19}\right)=\left(\dfrac{2}{19}\right)\left(\dfrac{5}{19}\right)=(-1)\left(\dfrac45\right)=-1\pmod{19}$.